# What is the equivalent for directive, compile (pre/post) in TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, equivalent

I have a question what is the equivalent for directive: compile (pre/post)?

Example in javascript:

```
angular.module('app').directive('checkBox', function () {
  return {
      //... my directive options

      compile: function () {
           return function () {
               pre: function (scope) {}
               post: function (scope) {}
           }
      }
  }
});
```

What is TypeScript equivalent for this?

Comment: Typescript is just Javascript, so it would be the same. You would probably just want to annotate the scope types with ng.IScope

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will be equivalent to:

```
public compile = (element: JQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes, transclude: any): DirectivePrePost => {
            return {
                pre: ($scope: any, element: JQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes) => {

                },
                post: ($scope: any, element: JQuery, attrs: angular.IAttributes) => {

                }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

if you use the reference from http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/

it is like

```
compile = (tElem: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, tAttrs: ng.IAttributes, transclude: ng.ITranscludeFunction): ng.IDirectivePrePost => {
            return {
                pre: (scope: IOrderDetailDirScope, iElem: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, iAttrs: ng.IAttributes) => {

                },
                post: (scope: IOrderDetailDirScope, iElem: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, iAttrs: ng.IAttributes) => {

                }
            };
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the return value from `compile` incorrect. You are supposed to return an object not a function:

```
compile: function () {
           return { // no `function ()`
               pre: function (scope) {}
               post: function (scope) {}
           }
      }
```

This code snippet will work as is with TypeScript.

Comment: Wrong what? Your answer is too vague. please correct it.

Comment: Basarat is saying the return from value from the compile function should be an object, not a function. If you look at his example, it is very clear.  You are returning function() {... } you should be returning an object {... }

Comment: How it concern my question? It erelevant